# Automatic Login - Based Off Checkbox Selection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, salesforce

Project Framework: .Net 4.5
Database 1: Salesforce
Local Database: MSSMS

I'm working on a demo for working with Salesforce API. This demo should allow users to select a checkbox for either the first or second company. Once selected, and a "Submit" button is pressed the OnClick action should pull in the appropriate login information from the Local DB, and essentially fill in the login credentials and push the client through to another page.

I've never worked with automatic login before. Is there a particular class, framework, script etc. that I'd need in order to enable this in my demo application. This demo is working in real-time with the SalesForce DB, as well as a locally hosted DB.

Comment: If you have the ability to get the credentials from Salesforce, I suppose you could put the credentials inside a cookie with, say, `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`. Then check to see if the cookie exists.

Comment: @DrewKennedy These particular credentials are stored in the local DB, and need to be pulled at the first instance, rather than stored for future use.